# How can we add the Open Gov to the solochain?

Tags: solo-chain, opengov

I have a solochain running on prod now i need to add the Open Gov to the chain to make the chain decentralize.

Can you please share some reference/resources to help me in that process.

Answer (score 3):

The best resource is to take a look into this PR by Gavin: [Introduce OpenGov into Polkadot](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/6701). You can ignore the code to remove Gov1 and just focus on the one adding Open Gov to Polkadot.

If you have Gov1 and want the migration too OpenGov read this forum post: [Gov V1 to OpenGov: A Technical Migration Guide](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/gov-v1-to-opengov-a-technical-migration-guide/4116)

Comment: Thanks for the reference.
As this reference is to change the code if chain having gov1 to opengov.
In my case we don't have any governance for now on our chain. We are just using POA for now. Is there reference specifically for that?